# Calculate the speed of the slowest flying machine in Minecraft with probabilities

Tags: probability

In Minecraft (sandbox video game made of blocks,written in Java), I have recently created a flying machine (assemble of blocks which moves on its own) and I have trouble calculating its speed, I hope someone can help me. Topic : *probabilities*

## Context [vocab and general context]:

Minecraft runs on a clock, steping 20 times per second. **There are 20 'game ticks'** (gt for short) **in a second**, 72 000 gt per hour.
Thunderstorm is a weather in the game and only during this weather, lightning bolts can appear. A chunk is a 16 wide *16 long *256 high piece of the world.

**The duration of thunderstorms is between 3 600 and 15 600 gt** (3 mins to 13 mins) with a pseudorandom uniform distribution [for details it is drawn with `java.util.Random.nextInt(int bound = 12000)+3600`]

The duration of 'clear' weather (**time between thunderstorms**) is similarly drawn but with bound of 168000 and added 12000 making it **from 12 000 to 180 000 gt**.
It is assumed that the player don't sleep(=drawn time is the actual time between thunders).

During (only) thunder weather, there is a 1/(100 000) chance per gt of a lightning bolt occuring in a chunk.
A lighting bolt position in a chunk is randomly selected using a LCG (linear congruential generator) [with parameters $a=3,c=1013904223$ and $m=2^{32}$ for formula $X_{n+1} = (a*X_n + c) \mod m$] and can (I think) be associated with a uniform distribution for the coordinates of the position along the two horizontal axis [given basically by `((LCG >> 2) & 15)` for one axis and `((LCG >> 2) >> 8 ) & 15` ] and the vertical coordinate is given by the block at the highest position (top-most block vertically).

There is then a $\dfrac{1}{100\, 000} * \dfrac{1}{16*16} = \dfrac{1}{25\, 600\, 000} $ chance per gt of a lighting bolt hitting a block (my block is placed to be the highest in its column of blocks) when it is thundering. [these probabilities are independant, therefore multiply them to get the proba of both happening, the target block can only be in 1 chunk at a time]

My flying machine need, to progress 1 block forward, 1 lighting bolt hit on 1 block [a piston that reacts to the lightning bolt] and to move 2 blocks forward, it requires 2 lightning bolts, **spaced in time by 9 gt** and the second lightning bolt (bolt for short) needs to happen at a different coordinate than the previous one (1 block offset in a horizontal direction). The targeted block may have moved to a different chunk (I don't think it changes the results).

If the second bolt did not happen at the right place/time, then the flying machine flies back in the other direction with a speed of 10gt per block (as opposed to the 9gt per block of the +X movement).
We have these two 'forces' opposing : the random lightning bolts pushing the flying machine forward (let's say in the +X direction) while another circuit pushes the flying machine backwards (-X direction) if bolts are not received at the right time and place.

## Problem

Based on the context, you probably think that the flying machine mostly goes in the -X direction seeing how rare thunderstorms and lightning bolts are (its true !), the problem formulates as follows :

### What is the probability that this machine travels 30 M(million) blocks in the +X direction ?

## Resolution attemp :

We'll start by seeing a few usefull observations then formulate more clearly then I will describe my attempt.

### Observations

The flying machine is faster in the +X direction (9gt per block) than in the -X direction (10gt per block).

There is a lot more time on average where it is not thundering as the average off thunder (no thunderstorms) is 96 000 gt (consecutive)(80 mins) while the average thunderstorm duration is only 9 600 gt(consecutive)(8 mins).

The maximum distance traveled during a thunderstorm (+X direction) (15 600gt) is $\frac{15600 }{9} = \frac{5200}{3} \approx 1\, 733.\overline{3}$ blocks while the minimum distance traveled during clear weather (-X direction(dir for short)) is $\frac{12000 }{10} = 1200$ blocks which is less than the maximum +X dir distance, with a maximum overall forward distance of $\frac{5200}{3}-1200=\frac{1600}{3} \approx 533.\overline{3}$ blocks ==> it is possible to overall go forward.

For the maximum thunderstorm duration, the given clear weather duration that moves the same distance (but opposite direction) is $\frac{15600 }{9}*10 = \frac{52000}{3} \approx 17333.\overline{3}$ gt (which is an integer in reality).
This means that any clear weather duration over this number will result in a total (during a cycle thunder, no thunder) distance in the -X direction no matter the thunderstorm duration.

Oppositely, for the maximum clear weather duration, the maximum number of blocks progressed in the -X direction is $\frac{180 000}{10} = 18 \,000$ blocks as, even during a thunderstorm, it is not garanted to go forward at all (no lightning bolts)

### Mathematical formulation

A parameter $F$ (forward) is given initialy by a random uniform distribution (integers) $U(3\, 600,15 \, 600)$

A parameter $B$ (backward) is given initialy  by a random uniform distribution (integers) $U(12\, 000,180 \, 000)$

A parameter $L$ (lightning bolt) is given by a descrete probability $p_L = \dfrac{1}{25\, 600 \, 000}$

A parameter $T$ (thundering) that is true or false (1 or 0) that says when it is thundering

A parameter $x_n$ (position from the origin ($x_0=0$)) of the flying machine with conditions that $x_n>0,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

The pseudo algorithm of the process is described here

```
When T switches from 0 to 1 : draw F
When T switches from 1 to 0 : draw B

If T is 1: (thunderstorm)
    cycle F number of times:
        if cooldown is 0: 
             draw L (lightning bolt occur ?)
        otherwise :
             subtract 1 from cooldown
        if L is 1 (success):
            cooldown is set to 9 gt
            x_n is increased by 1
            L is to 0
        if cooldown is -1 :
            x_n is decreased by 1
            cooldown is set to 10
    set T to 0 once cycle is finished
if T is 0 : (clear weather)
    x_n is decreased by min(x_n,B/10)
    (min to not become negative
    set T to 1
```

**The goal is to calculate the time taken on average for x_n to reach 30 000 000.**

### My resolution attempt

I tried to bound the minimum time : from the previous observations, we can travel forward (+X dir) as maximum of 533 blocks every thunder and clear weather cycle, so every 27 600 gt.
This gives us the shortest time possible with perfect luck of $ \frac{27600}{533}\times 30\, 000 \, 000 = 1 553 470 920$ gt (59.1 years (fast!))

Then I tried to estimate it using gambler's ruin but am not sure at all if I used it corectly.
There are 6 480 000 couples (thunder, clear) with a positive amount of ticks (thunder gt-clear gt) out of the 2 016 000 000 couples possible, giving a probability of 0.32142857 % to have a couple with more thunder gt than clear gt.

Doing the sum of the values of all the couples (thunder gt-clear gt) gives a value of 7 782 481 200, which I after multiplied it by probability of it beeing positive to give the overal expected value of positive couples : $p =25\, 015\, 118$.

then using this formula I found online, we can calculate the expected nb of gt to have to wait to have 9*30M gt :
$ p+ \dfrac{\left(p\right)^{9*30*10^6-1}-1}{p-1}$
Which gives a result of around $10^{(10^{9.3})}$

That is the expected time to wait before the thunder/clear weather cycle give the right conditions to reach the goal with perfect lighting bolts luck.

To take into account I use the same formula but swapping the $p$ for the $1/p_L$ (average time between good lighting bolts and with the time calculated above, giving the formula

$ \dfrac{1}{p_L}+ \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{p_L}\right)^{10^{(10^{9.3})}-1}-1}{\dfrac{1}{p_L}-1}$
Which gives a result of (around) $10^{(10^{(10^{(9.3)})})}$ gt

Which is very slow !

### Conclusion

I am really not sure about these calculations and would like if anyone could guide me to find the speed of this machine. It is expected to take a lot longer than $7*10^{9*10^7}$ but the upper bound has no estimate.
I would gladly answer any questions about details or general questions to help resolve this problem.

Thank you for reading !